# Is there a way to use a slicer to change individual measures in a bar graph in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Basically, I want to display a bar graph with two columns containing identical measures that i've created (count of individuals across all tables) called IND_COUNT1 and IND_COUNT2. I want to create two different slicers that independtly filter each measure (bar) in the graph.

So when year slicer #1 is set to 2023, IND_COUNT1 (the first bar) displays the count of 2023, while  IND_COUNT2 (the second bar) would remain the same (showing the total count).

Then when year slicer #2 is set to 2024, the IND_COUNT2 filters the count of individuals to just display 2022, while the first bar would continue to display 2023, thus comparing the count between the two years.

I've tried using measures in the slicer filters but nothing has given me the result i'm looking for, so now i'm wondering if this is even possible in Power Bi.